# Codeigniter 3 using datatable cant get data using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, datatable, codeigniter-3

I found an error with my coding.
I here want to display data in DataTables with ajax. For the filter itself, it is dynamic so that the filter can be more than 1 depending on what is made. But when I want to display the data, there is an error which I don't know which side is the error. Here's the script:

By the way, im using CodeIgniter 3
View

```
    <section class="content-header">
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom: 15px;  ">
            <div style="background-color: #E9fbf0; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; background-position:center; padding: 30 0 0 10;  border-radius: 15px; border:1px solid black;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="action-th">Departemen</th>
                                <td><? echo $biodataSiswa['departemen']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="action-th">Tahun Ajaran</th>
                                <td><? echo $biodataSiswa['tahunajaran']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="action-th">Kelas</th>
                                <td><? echo $biodataSiswa['kelas']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="action-th">NIS</th>
                                <td><? echo $biodataSiswa['nis']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="idmodul" name="idmodul" value="<? echo $idtabel; ?>"/>
                <form id="filter-form">
                    <div class="row">
                      <?  $no = 0;
                          foreach ($filter as $row) { ?>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
                                <label for=""><? echo $row?></label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="f_<? echo $no; ?>" name="f_<? echo $no; ?>">
                                    <option value=''>Pilih</option>
                                    <? foreach ($f_[$no] as $row) : ?>
                                        <option value='<? echo $row['f1']; ?>'><? echo $row['f2']; ?> </option>
                                    <? endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                      <? $no++;} ?>
                            <br>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top:20px;">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary d-inline">
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <br>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="example" style="width:100%;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Pelajaran</th>
                                        <th>Nilai Angka</th>
                                        <th>Nilai Huruf</th>
                                        <th>Keterangan</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- <div class="col-md-12">
                    <br>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Pelajaran</th>
                                    <th>Nilai Angka</th>
                                    <th>Nilai Huruf</th>
                                    <th>Keterangan</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>




    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable;
            // var id = $('#idmodul').val();
            dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
              "ajax": {
                   url : "<? echo base_url('viewtabel/ambil'); ?>",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: {
                           filter_data : function(){
                               return $('#filter-form').serialize();
                           },
                           idmodul : function(){
                               return $('#idmodul').val();
                           }
                         }
               },
               "columnDefs": [{
                    "defaultContent": "-",
                    "targets": "_all"
                }],
               "aoColumns": [
                    {data : "f1"},
                    {data : "f2"},
                    {data : "f3"},
                    {data : "f4"}
               ],
               "scrollCollapse": true,
               "fixedColumns": {
                    "left": 1
                },
               'processing': true,
               'language': {
                    "loadingRecords": '&nbsp;',
                    "processing" : '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px;color:rgb(75, 183, 245);"></i>'
               },
               "scrollX": true,
            });

            $('#filter-form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
            })
        });
    </script>
```

And, this is the Controller

```
<?

Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //for allow any domain, insecure
Header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *'); //for allow any headers, insecure
Header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'); //method allowed

class Viewtabel extends CI_Controller{

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper(array('path'));
    $this->load->model('M_siswa');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('M_all');
    $this->load->library('lib_connection');
    $this->load->library('lib_menu');
    $this->load->library('lib_menu_akademik');
    $this->load->library('lib_changedate_toindo');
    $this->load->library('lib_menu_departemen');
    $this->db2 = $this->load->database('jibA', TRUE);
    $this->db3 = $this->load->database('jibB', TRUE);
  }

  public function index() {

        $accessToken = $this->session->userdata('token');
        $link_api = $this->session->userdata('link_api');
        $data['data_website'] = $this->M_all->getWesbiteData();

        $arr_segment=$this->uri->segment_array();
        if(isset($arr_segment[2])){
           $action=strtolower(urldecode($arr_segment[2]));
        } else
          $action="";

        switch($action){
          default:
            echo "Modul Tabel";
            break;
          case "load":

            $data['data_website'] = $this->M_all->getWesbiteData();
            $data['rows_menu3'] = $this->lib_menu_akademik->generate_menu();

            $nis = $this->session->userdata('nis');
            $emailtagihan = $this->session->userdata('email');

            $bioSiswa = $this->M_siswa->getSiswaWithNis($nis,$emailtagihan);
            $dataSiswa = $this->M_siswa->getDataByNis($nis);
            $idKelas = $dataSiswa['idkelas'];

            $id = $arr_segment[3];
            $dataTabel = $this->M_all->getDataTabel($id);

            $this->session->set_userdata('idmodul',$id = $arr_segment[3]);

            $arrFilter = explode(',', $dataTabel['nama_filter']);
            $arrQueryF = explode(' | ', $dataTabel['query_filter']);
            $connection_id = $dataTabel['connection'];

                $arrQueryF=str_replace('@NIS', "'".$nis."'",$arrQueryF);
            $arrQueryF=str_replace('@DEPART', "'".$bioSiswa['departemen']."'",$arrQueryF);

            // print_r($arrQueryF);


            // print_R($arrQueryF);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrQueryF); $i++){
              $arrQ[] = $this->M_siswa->getFilter($arrQueryF[$i]);
              $data['f_'][$i] = $arrQ[$i];

            }

            $data['filter'] = $arrFilter;
            // print_r($dataTabel['pk_tablebaru']); 

            $data['idtabel'] = $dataTabel['pk_tablebaru'];

            $data['biodataSiswa'] = $bioSiswa;
            $tglIndo = $this->lib_changedate_toindo->ubahIndo($bioSiswa['tgllahir']);
            $data['tgllahirsiswa'] = $tglIndo;

            $this->load->view("v_modultabel2.inc.php",$data);
            break;
          case "setting":

            $ch5 = curl_init($link_api. 'extrarest/login-user');
            curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken));
            curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $oUser2 = json_decode(curl_exec($ch5));

            $dept_uid = $oUser2->department;
            $listmenu = $this->M_all->getMenuFromDepartemen($dept_uid);
            $data['menuPerDept'] = $listmenu;
            $data['menunya'] = $this->M_all->getMenu();
            //$data['rows_menu'] = $this->lib_menu->generate_menu();
            $data['rows_menu2'] = $this->lib_menu_departemen->generate_menu($dept_uid,$this->session->userdata('group'),$this->session->userdata('uid'));

            $ch1 = curl_init($link_api. 'user/'. $this->session->userdata('uid'));
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken));
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $oUser2 = json_decode(curl_exec($ch1));

            if (!isset($oUser2)) {
               print "Error accessing $link_api: \n" . curl_error($ch1);
            }
            elseif (isset($oUser2->error)) {

            }
            else {
            }
            curl_close($ch1);



            $data['loguser'] = $oUser2;
            $data['data_workspace'] = $this->M_all->getLinkApi1();
            $data['data_website'] = $this->M_all->getWesbiteData();

            //$mymenu=new Lib_menu();
            //$ret=$mymenu-> generate_menu();

            //$data=array('base_url'=>$base_url,'rows_menu'=>$ret);
            //print_r($data['rows_menu']['level_1']);
            $data_sidebar=$this->lib_menu->sidebar_menu();

            $data['koneksi'] = $this->M_all->getAllConnection();


            $this->load->view('v_modultabel2', $data);
            $this->load->view("sidebar.php",$data_sidebar);
            break;
          case "post":
            $nama_tabel = $this->input->post('nama_tabel');
            $nama_filter = $this->input->post('nama_filter');
            $query_filter = $this->input->post('query_filter');
            $kolom_tabel = $this->input->post('kolom_tabel');
            $query_data = $this->input->post('queryData');
            $connection_id = $this->input->post('connection_id');

            if($_POST['insert_mode']==1){
              $postParams = array(
                'pk_tablebaru' => '',
                'nama_tabel' => $nama_tabel,
                'nama_filter' => $nama_filter,
                'query_filter' => $query_filter,
                'kolom_tabel' => $kolom_tabel,
                'query_data' => $query_data,
                'connection' => $connection_id,
              );

              $this->M_all->InsertToTableBaru('tb_tablebaru',$postParams);

              $last_id = $this->M_all->getLastIDTBBaru();
              $l_id = $last_id['max(pk_tablebaru)'];
              $url = base_url()."viewtabel/load/$l_id";
              $this->db->query("UPDATE tb_tablebaru SET url = '$url' WHERE pk_tablebaru = '$l_id'");

              redirect ('/viewtabel/setting/');
            }

            break;
          case "del":
            break;
          case "ambil":
            $filter_data = $this->input->post('filter_data');
            parse_str($filter_data, $params);


            $nis = $this->session->userdata('nis');
            $idmodul = $this->session->userdata('idmodul');
            $dataTabel = $this->M_all->getDataTabel($idmodul);


            $queryDataTabel = $dataTabel['query_data']; 

            $queryDataTabel=str_replace('@NIS', "'".$nis."'",$queryDataTabel);
            $queryDataTabel=str_replace('@f1','"'.$params['f_1'].'"',$queryDataTabel);
            $queryDataTabel=str_replace('@f2','"'.$params['f_0'].'"',$queryDataTabel);

            $getDatanya = $this->M_siswa->getDatanya($queryDataTabel);

            print_r($queryDataTabel);


            $json_data['data'] = $getDatanya;
            echo json_encode($json_data);
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

at the Controller, i want to get the data from database. The variables used to enter the data are **$getDatanya**
This is the query :

```
SELECT c.nama AS f1,b.nilaiangka as f2,b.nilaihuruf as f3,b.keterangan as f4 FROM tabelB b LEFT JOIN tabelC c ON c.replid = b.idpelajaran LEFT JOIN tabelA a ON b.nis = a.nis AND a.aktif = 1 WHERE b.nis = @NIS AND b.idkelas = @f1 AND b.idsemester = @f2
```

Hopefully I can find a solution here. Thank you very much.

Comment: "*there is an error*" - what is the error?

Comment: Hi, by the way im already solved this. The mistake is i write a print_r($queryDataTabel); because, maybe the system also reads the results of print_r. The data that is read by the system to display the data should only be json data.